# How to do WhiteBalance (or levels correction) using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, photo, levels

I’ve working in an app system that take the ID Photos, but the webcam whitebalance ajust isn’t perfect.

In the background we put an white fabric but it still look other color (kind of yellow, gray, blue, depending of the light at the moment of the snapshot).

I’m trying to work with the blend mode “hardlight” in the webcam, plus magicWand to remove the background and turn it completely white, but the skin tone doen’t look natural.

Using the levels correction in photoshop, I can define the right point of White and then use the MagicWand to clean the image.

How can I do the same using AS3?

Comment: look into ColorMatrix and the Color class

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the paletteMap functionality built into bitmapData. It allows you to replace colour values on a per colour index basis.

You could, in theory, use a picker to choose the White balance point, and then use that as an offset for the palletteMap values.

Read more about palletteMap here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#paletteMap()